# Does mixing actions in a card feed confuse users?

Tags: cards, card-sorting

Imagine a card-style feed where users can only see one card at a time. Each card has at least two calls to action. Most cards are presented in a y/n format where swiping right means "yes" and swiping left means "no". Would adding cards into the same feed which have different, non-swipable CTAs confuse users? The non-swipable cards would be visually different than the swipable y/n cards with bolder, text based CTAs opposed to and x and check marks in the y/n format.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to reduce user confusion that you use additional visual distinction for the non-swipable cards that go beyond different CTAs. Perhaps a different visual treatment, color and even card shape - to help users discriminate between the different card types and applicable CTAs.  Try a few mockups that you can test with users as well, to ensure that they understand the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

## Pattern Breaking is Good!

(Question is **why** and **how**. )

In UX, **context is everything**. And part of the context is *why* to do something, where most of the times, *why* is answered with *"site/app/user/company needs to make money"* (surprise!).

What you're asking is a very common UX tool known as **[Pattern Breaking](http://thehipperelement.com/post/73305160526/daily-ux-crash-course-14-of-31)**. The whole idea behind this is... to do EXACTLY what you mention. **If in doubt, ask Facebook!**

Now, this doesn't meat that, because you want to break a pattern, you're allowed to do whatever you want. pattern breaking has rules by itself, but as long as you follow them, you're good to go. And based on your description, it sounds like you're on good track.

All this being said: *test, test, test!*

Edit: on top of the reasons mentioned above, not breaking the pattern could end in highly unethical, "fishy" approaches. Making a CTA look the same as a regular card (for example a post) can only be seen as an intent to cheat the user to do something s/he doesn't want to do voluntarily. Well identified CTAs are good for business, literally no cons

Comment: Awesome feedback, thank you! I was hoping pattern breaking in this instance could help ensure the users take the intended action without being tricked into it, but didn't want to make the cognitive load too much

Answer (score 0):

If you introduce an additional interaction to your simple tinder style card sorting pattern usability is going to suffer. I would go back and rethink the customer benefit and see if there is another way to frame the calls to action to fit the pattern you have already established. If you absolutely can't make it fit and need to expand beyond the binary Y/N make the changes consistent across all the cards. Don't make me think!